# Expo-cli installing halts with error npm ERR! cb() never called

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I tried installing expo-cli but unfortunately it halted with the errors below.

```
freduah@freduah:~$ npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/freduah/.npm/_logs/2021-09-28T14_47_55_893Z-debug.log
freduah@freduah:~$
```

I tried to report it to the `npm community` but the community was no longer

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows, add/allow NodeJS JavaScript Runtime through firewall in your network.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).